# Upon Button Click Display Pop-Up for Certain Time and then Redirect Page - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, response.redirect

I have a form.
Upon clicking a submit button, I want to display a message (say: ""Submitted Successfully) as a pop-up.
The pop-up must stay for about 3 seconds and after that I want to reload/redirect the page.

I am aware that I can achieve this using jQuery. 
But I want to know if there is a way to achieve this through asp.net/C# which I can write in the cs file of the aspx page.

How do I achieve this?

Below is the button-click method I have written currently. Notice the code: `thread.sleep(3000)` - during this 3 second delay I want to show a pop-up.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Demo_UserInfo values (@UserID, 'FX1234', (select ReleaseID from Demo_ReleaseInfo where ProductName='asd'), 0)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", txtUserID.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();        

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/MapReleaseItem.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You have to do this in javascript, the code behind executes on the server not in the browser. The closest you can do in the code behind is send javascript back to the page which will be executed when the page loads.

Comment: @BenRobinson you mean something like: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", "MyMethodName()", true);

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @BenRobinson Alright. I will do that. I was hoping asp.net had some option to do that via the cs file. Thanks!

Comment: @BenRobinson How do I show a loading image while my code takes times to hit the DB, execute the query and return control back to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a loader instead 
[This article can help you](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-image-while-PostBack-calls-in-ASPNet.aspx)